# How can I use accents (like tilde) in the keywords of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

Here's my code in algoritmo.tex:

```
Foi usado o algoritmo 1 em MATLAB para resolver o problema $\mathop{min}_{x \in\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)$.

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Método da Região de Confiança implementado }
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Objetivo
\Desc{Encontrar uma solução aproximada para o problema $\mathop{min}_{x \in\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)$.}
\EndObjetivo
\Input 
\Desc{Uma função f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}$.}
\Desc{Gradiente da função ${\nabla}$f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}^{n}$.}
\Desc{Hessiana da função ${\nabla}^{2}$f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}^{n{\times}n}$.}
\Desc{Iterada inicial $x_{0} \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.}
\Desc{O raio da região de confiança ${\Delta}_{0}$.}
\Desc{A precisão desejada $\epsilon \in\mathbb{R}, \epsilon>0$.}
\Desc{Os parâmetros $0 < {\eta}_{1} \leq {\eta}_{2} < 1$.}
\EndInput
\Output
\Desc{Uma aproximação da solução óptima $x^{*} \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.}
\Desc{O número de iterações k.}
\Desc{Um array com todas as iterações de $x_{k}$, o respetivo valor}
\Desc{da função $f(x_{k})$, a norma dos gradiente $\|{\nabla}f(x_{k})\| \in\mathbb{R}$,}
\Desc{o respetivo ${\rho}$ e o tipo de passo feito.}
\Desc{O estado da iteração num array de strings, pobre (-), bom (+),}
\Desc{muito bom (++).}
\EndOutput
\Inicializacao
\Desc{k:=0}
\EndInicializacao
\Repetir
\Desc{Calcular $p_{k}$ ao resolver o subproblema (\ref{SubProblema}) com o método de dogleg}
\Desc{ou com o Gradiente Conjugado de Steihaug.}
\Desc{$\rho := \frac{f(x_{k}) - f(x_{k}+p_{k})}{m_{x_{k}}(x_{k})-m_{x_{k}}(x_{k} + p_{k})}$}
\Se { }$\rho < \eta_{1}$ então
\Desc{$x_{k+1} := x_{k}$}
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := \frac{1}{2}{\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSe
\Senao 
\Desc{$x_{k+1} := x_{k} + p_{k}$}
\Se { }$\rho \geq \eta_{2}$ então
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := 2{\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSe
\Senao
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := {\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSenao
\EndSenao
\Desc{$k:= k + 1$}
\EndRepetir
\Ate { }$\|{\nabla}f(x_{k})\| \leq \epsilon$ ou $k > 500$
\EndAte 

$NumeroIteracoes := k , x^{*} := x_{k}$  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

In my main.tex i use this:

```
...
\algblock{Objetivo}{EndObjetivo}
\algnotext{EndObjetivo}
\algblock{Input}{EndInput}
\algnotext{EndInput}
\algblock{Output}{EndOutput}
\algnotext{EndOutput}
\algblock{Inicializacao}{EndInicializacao}
\algnotext{EndInicializacao}
\algblock{Repetir}{EndRepetir}
\algnotext{EndRepetir}
\algblock{Ate}{EndAte}
\algnotext{EndAte}
\algblock{Se}{EndSe}
\algnotext{EndSe}
\algblock{Senao}{EndSenao}
\algnotext{EndSenao}
\newcommand{\Desc}[1]{\State \makebox[2em][l]{#1}}
```

If i use the ~ there i get errors.

And here's the output:

[image]

Instead of "Senao", "Inicializacao" and "Ate" i wanted Senão, Inicialização and Até but for reason it doesn't appear that way.

Also, do you guys got any clue how can i add vertical lines and "NumeroIteracoes = k" become "NúmeroIterações = k" and have line number 36 in its left?

Comment: Whatever else you do, please replace all instances of `\mathop{min}` in your document with `\min`. And, do replace all instances of `NumeroIteracoes=k` that occur in math mode with `\textrm{NúmeroIterações}=k`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `\algblockdefx` variant to specify the start/end text with the accents, and the command names without? For example, something like `\algblockdefx{Ate}{EndAte}{Até}{EndAté}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of the short form for defining new blocks

   ```
   \algblock{Ate}{EndAte}
   ```

   use the long form:

   ```
   \algblockdefx{Ate}{EndAte}{\textbf{Até}}{\textbf{EndAté}}
   ```

   The first two parameters become the names of the commands, `\Ate` and `\EndAte`, while the third and fourth parameter give the text printed for starting and ending the block. For details, see page 14 of the [package documentation](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf), also available from the command line via `texdoc algorithmicx`.
2. The commands `\SetAlgoLined` and `\DontPrintSemicolon` will not work, since they belong to a different package for typesetting algorithms, `algorithm2e`, while you seem to use `algorithmicx`.
3. Use `\textit{NúmeroIterações}` instead of `NúmeroIterações` in math mode. This has two effects: The UTF characters works (you get accents), and the spacing between letters will correspond to letters in a word and not to single-letter variables.
4. Precede normal statements by the keyword `\State`. This will take care of indentation and numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\algblock{Objetivo}{EndObjetivo}
\algnotext{EndObjetivo}
\algblock{Input}{EndInput}
\algnotext{EndInput}
\algblock{Output}{EndOutput}
\algnotext{EndOutput}
\algblockdefx{Inicializacao}{EndInicializacao}{\textbf{Inicialização}}{\textbf{EndInicialização}}
\algnotext{EndInicializacao}
\algblock{Repetir}{EndRepetir}
\algnotext{EndRepetir}
\algblockdefx{Ate}{EndAte}{\textbf{Até}}{\textbf{EndAté}}
\algnotext{EndAte}
\algblock{Se}{EndSe}
\algnotext{EndSe}
\algblockdefx{Senao}{EndSenao}{\textbf{Senão}}{\textbf{EndSenão}}
\algnotext{EndSenao}
\newcommand{\Desc}[1]{\State \makebox[2em][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Objetivo
\Desc{Encontrar uma solução aproximada para o problema $\mathop{min}_{x \in\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)$.}
\EndObjetivo
\Input 
\Desc{Uma função f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}$.}
\Desc{Gradiente da função ${\nabla}$f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}^{n}$.}
\Desc{Hessiana da função ${\nabla}^{2}$f: ${\mathbb{R}}^{n} {\rightarrow} {\mathbb{R}}^{n{\times}n}$.}
\Desc{Iterada inicial $x_{0} \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.}
\Desc{O raio da região de confiança ${\Delta}_{0}$.}
\Desc{A precisão desejada $\epsilon \in\mathbb{R}, \epsilon>0$.}
\Desc{Os parâmetros $0 < {\eta}_{1} \leq {\eta}_{2} < 1$.}
\EndInput
\Output
\Desc{Uma aproximação da solução óptima $x^{*} \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.}
\Desc{O número de iterações k.}
\Desc{Um array com todas as iterações de $x_{k}$, o respetivo valor}
\Desc{da função $f(x_{k})$, a norma dos gradiente $\|{\nabla}f(x_{k})\| \in\mathbb{R}$,}
\Desc{o respetivo ${\rho}$ e o tipo de passo feito.}
\Desc{O estado da iteração num array de strings, pobre (-), bom (+),}
\Desc{muito bom (++).}
\EndOutput
\Inicializacao
\Desc{k:=0}
\EndInicializacao
\Repetir
\Desc{Calcular $p_{k}$ ao resolver o subproblema (\ref{SubProblema}) com o método de dogleg}
\Desc{ou com o Gradiente Conjugado de Steihaug.}
\Desc{$\rho := \frac{f(x_{k}) - f(x_{k}+p_{k})}{m_{x_{k}}(x_{k})-m_{x_{k}}(x_{k} + p_{k})}$}
\Se { }$\rho < \eta_{1}$ então
\Desc{$x_{k+1} := x_{k}$}
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := \frac{1}{2}{\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSe
\Senao 
\Desc{$x_{k+1} := x_{k} + p_{k}$}
\Se { }$\rho \geq \eta_{2}$ então
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := 2{\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSe
\Senao
\Desc{${\Delta}_{k+1} := {\Delta}_{k}$}
\EndSenao
\EndSenao
\Desc{$k:= k + 1$}
\EndRepetir
\Ate { }$\|{\nabla}f(x_{k})\| \leq \epsilon$ ou $k > 500$
\EndAte

\State $\textit{NúmeroIterações} := k , x^{*} := x_{k}$  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

---

**How to change the caption of algorithms to another language (here: Portuguese)**

In the preamble, add the following lines after `\usepackage{algorithm}`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ALG@name{Algoritmo}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\listalgorithmname{Lista de Algoritmos}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ALG@name{Algoritmo}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\listalgorithmname{Lista de Algoritmos}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Método 1}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Método 2}
\end{algorithm}
\listofalgorithms
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works good except i wanted "Algoritmo 1" and not "Algorithm 1". Is there a way to change that?

Comment: @Scipio I have updated my answer, see the end.